# how do I create a while loop for guessing the letters in a word until the word is complete?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have written the following program:

```
prompt_1 = '3.8% of the world\'s population suffer from __________'
answer_1 = 'depression'
print(prompt_1)
output = '__________'
def evaluate_guess():
    guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    while output != answer_1:
        while len(guess) > 1:
            print('only one character please.')
            guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
        for char in answer_1:
            if guess in char:
                output.replace(output[answer_1.find(guess)], guess)
        print(output)
        guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    return output
print(evaluate_guess())
```

I have tried using the name.replace method in other programs with some success but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working here

My goal is to write a program where the user will guess the letters in a word in a sentance until they get all the words right. with each correct letter the user provides, that letter becomes visible in the sentence and remains that way unti the end, but instead of that word keeps printing as empty and doesn't appear even after all the correct letters were guesses. here are the results of the program:

```
3.8% of the world's population suffer from __________
guess a letter from the missing word: d
__________
guess a letter from the missing word: r
__________
guess a letter from the missing word:
```

any advice?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: output.replace doesn't do in-place replacement. it's creating a new string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also pass parameters to your function, this will avoid the majority of problems working with variables outside of the function: `def evaluate_guess(answer, result):`

The replacement I used was transforming the output in a list, than changing the the _ in the right position to the correct guess and transforming everything in a string again:

```
# answer = answer_1 and result = output
for i in range(len(answer)):
    if guess in answer[i]:
        temp = list(result)  # Transforms result in a list
        temp[i] = guess  # Changes the _ on the position of the found letter to the right guess
        result = "".join(temp)  # Transforms the result in a string again and assign it to result itself
print(result)
```

And here is the whole code:

```
prompt_1 = '3.8% of the world\'s population suffer from __________'
answer_1 = 'depression'
print(prompt_1)
output = '__________'


def evaluate_guess(answer, result):  # answer = answer_1 and result = output
    guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    while result != answer:
        while len(guess) > 1:
            print('only one character, please.')
            guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
        for i in range(len(answer)):
            if guess in answer[i]:
                temp = list(result)  # Transforms result in a list
                temp[i] = guess  # Changes the _ on the position of the found letter to the right guess
                result = "".join(temp)  # Transforms the result in a string again and assign it to result itself
        print(result)
        guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    return result


print(evaluate_guess(answer_1, output))
```

Hope that's help!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
                output.replace(output[answer_1.find(guess)], guess)
```

Please understand that we do not evaluate `.replace( ... )` for
side effects on the `output` variable.
Rather, it produces a *new* string.
Which you discarded.

You were looking for this:

```
                output = output.replace(output[answer_1.find(guess)], guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code revolves around getting the input from the user and checking it, the heavy lifting is supposed to be here:

```
        for char in answer_1:
            if guess in char:
                output.replace(output[answer_1.find(guess)], guess)
```

However, there's a few mistakes piled on top of each other here:

- you loop over every character of `answer_1`, but don't keep track of the position, so you're missing some information you might need here.
- you check if `guess` is `in char`, but both `guess` and `char` are single characters, so you could just check if they are equal.
- you replace `output[answer_1.find(guess)]`, so that's the character at the first position of `guess` in `answer_1`, with `guess`. But if you entered `'d'`, that would be position 0, at which there is a `'_'`, so you're replacing all `'_'` with `'d'`
- except that you don't save the replacement - `.replace()` is not in-place, it returns the string with replacements, so the result is never captured and this discarded.
- finally, you do all this in a function, but reassigning to `output` (like you probably should) would shadow `output` from the global scope. The smallest adjustment here is to make `output` global, although it's not a nice way to handle this.

However, with a minimum of changes, to fix your code, you'd end up with something like:

```
prompt_1 = '3.8% of the world\'s population suffer from __________'
answer_1 = 'depression'
print(prompt_1)
output = '__________'
def evaluate_guess():
    global output
    guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    while output != answer_1:
        while len(guess) > 1:
            print('only one character please.')
            guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
        for i, char in enumerate(answer_1):
            if guess == char:
                # replacing the character in position i with guess
                output = output[:i] + guess + output[i+1:]
        print(output)
        guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    return output
print(evaluate_guess())
```

With a few more changes, this is closer to what I'd write if I were writing a program with similar output and function:

```
def play_game(hint, answer):
    result = '_' * len(answer)
    print(hint)
    while result != answer:
        guess = input('guess a letter from the missing word: ')
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('exactly one character per guess please.')
            continue
        result = ''.join([
            guess if guess == answer[i] else result[i] for i in range(len(answer))
        ])
        print(result)


prompt_1 = '3.8% of the world\'s population suffer from __________'
answer_1 = 'depression'
play_game(prompt_1, answer_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this, is first to figure out the indices of where the letter given appears in the answer. You could use the method `string.index(letter)` but this does not return every location of where the letter appears. For example, in the word 'depression' the letter 's' appears twice.

To solve this, we create the following method, which returns and array of indices which represent the location(s) of the given letter in the given word.

```
"""
Returns an array of all indexes of the word which contains the letter given
"""
def allIndexsOf(letter, word):
    return [i for i in range(len(word)) if word[i] == letter]
```

Using this function, we check for all location(s) of the guess in the answer. Note that if the letter does not appear, the return list will be empty and the for loop will be skipped.

```
# Fill in output
for i in allIndexsOf(guess, answer_1):
      tmp = list(output)
      tmp[i] = guess
      output = "".join(tmp)
```

Final code:

```
def evaluate_guess():
    prompt_1 = '3.8% of the world\'s population suffer from __________'
    answer_1 = 'depression'
    print(prompt_1)
    output = '__________'
    guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    while output != answer_1:
        while len(guess) > 1:
            print('only one character please.')
            guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")

        # Fill in output
        for i in allIndexsOf(guess, answer_1):
            tmp = list(output)
            tmp[i] = guess
            output = "".join(tmp)


        print(output)
        guess = input("guess a letter from the missing word: ")
    return output

print(evaluate_guess())
```